# sscanf converting from octal: How does it know?

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I have this code which converts a string to an int

```c
unsigned int formatInt(char *ptr) {
    int res;
    if (sscanf(ptr, "%i", &res) == -1) exit(-1);
    return res;
}
```

I fed it a `char *` pointing to the first char of "00000000041".

Conversion to `int` returns me 33 (Implicit Octal to Decimal conversion)

"00000000041" is actually a string (`char[12]`), but it's the size of a file in octal.

How did the compiler know it was in octal ? 00000000041 could perfectly be a decimal (41)

Comment: `scanf` *doesn't* "convert to decimal" but it can convert *from* decimal. When you use `%i` it detects octal from the leading `0`, but not when you use `%d`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why would the leading 0 mean octal ? It could perfectly mean decimal.
041 could be 41.

Sorry I did not get "convert from decimal". Here, I feed it an "octal" it detected, and %i returned a decimal. So technically its from octal to decimal right ?

Comment: It is by definition. And it isn't "to decimal" but to binary. Numbers are stored as decimal in strings, or in BCD notation.

Comment: `"%i"` means "if there is a leading zero, treat it as octal".

Comment: @Eljay haha i thaught %i meant match an int. Thanks all

Comment: It does. It's the original notation that is different from `%d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recognizing the string as octal is a function of the `%i` format specifier to `scanf`.  From the man page:

> ```
>    i      Matches an optionally signed integer; the next pointer must be a
>           pointer to int.  The integer is read in base  16  if  it  begins
>           with  0x  or  0X,  in base 8 if it begins with 0, and in base 10
>           otherwise.  Only characters that  correspond  to  the  base  are
>           used.
> ```

So because the string begins with a 0 and `%i` was used, it is interpreted as an octal string.